# Is system environment variable allowed in keycloak realm.json?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, keycloak

I'm using Keycloak to manage authentification of my app.

And using docker to build my keycloak image for both Dev and Prod environment.

Every time I build my docker image I import a new realm.json file and I have to modify manually the configuration to work with the corresponding environment ("Dev" & "Prod").

The idea is simply to use **system environment variable ** in the **realm.json**. I have tried to use  `{MY_ENV_VARIABLE}` and `{env.MY_ENV_VARIABLE}` but nothing seem to work.

Comment: "modify manually the configuration", which configuration do you mean? the realm json?

Comment: Yes, all we can found in the realm.json file (Realms, Clients, Mapper, Scopes ...). For now, I am willing to config clients RootUrl's, RedirectUris & WebOrigins with environment variables

Comment: I had similar issue, what I have done was to use a template realm.json, with the fields that are configurable, lets say "RootUrl's" : "<ROOTURI>", than I have a script that copies that template and replaces automatically the tags like <ROOTURI> with the correct contend.

Comment: I did the same thing with Shell to replace values and it works, but we usually work with env variables and I do not want to add extra logical layer. Are you saying that is NO WAY to use env variables in realm.json?

Comment: I think you will always have to inject then, so you have the extra layer, I don't think that the variables will be automatically changed. Have you had a look at this https://levelup.gitconnected.com/injecting-environment-variables-into-static-files-ea21c2d4bdbd

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to use environment variables in realm.json. The syntax is the usual "${VARIABLE_NAME}".

Docs: https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport

Comment: This substitution only works when Keycloak is started as `kc start/start-dev --import-realm`. It won't work if you run a standalone `kc import` command.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work what @Irmin said.
How I managed this:
Implement you custom 'dir' provider:

```
factory : CustomDirProviderFactory implements ImportProviderFactory {

provider: public class CustomDirProvider implements ImportProvider {
```

And there override method called

> public void importRealm(KeycloakSessionFactory factory, final String realmName, final Strategy strategy) throws IOException {

There before Realmreporesentation import, you can replace values from you json file:

```
// Import realm first
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(realmFile);
    final RealmRepresentation realmRep = JsonSerialization.readValue(replacePlaceHolders(enabledClient, clientSecret, is).getBytes(), RealmRepresentation.class);
```

replacing variables:

```
private String replacePlaceHolders(String enabledClient, String clientSecret, FileInputStream is) throws IOException {
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    String context = new String(is.readAllBytes(), charset);
    context = context.replaceAll("\\$\\{" + ENV_VAR_ENABLE_CLIENTS + "}", enabledClient);
    context = context.replaceAll("\\$\\{" + ENV_VAR_CLIENT_SECRET + "}", clientSecret);
    return context;
}
```

Of course add this file in resource folder and locate your provider:

```
resources/META-INF/services/org.keycloak.exportimport.ImportProviderFactory
```

In run jvm settings (in my compose) add this:

```
-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=custom-dir  (provider ID)
```